# Is there a way to execute Shipit "remote" commands that use "sudo" with a user other than root?

Tags: ssh, sudo

When using the [Shipit](https://github.com/shipitjs/shipit) automation engine I found that trying to execute commands with "sudo" from an user other than root (let's call it "devuser") **results in the connection closing without the command being executed**.
This is a command that I'm trying to execute:

> shipit.remote('**sudo** pwd');

Note that, on the target machine, "devuser" can execute everything with "sudo", without being asked his/her password (it's a choice of the target system).
Also note that everything invoked without "sudo" (and that obviously doesn't need elevated permission) gets executed prefectly fine by Shipit.
E.g.this one works just fine:

> shipit.remote('pwd');

The question at this point is: am I doing something wrong or is it this way by design (e.g. to avoid privileges escalation)?
If it's the latter: is there a way to work this limitation around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple hack for that is to set user inside each command that you are running with `shipit`. This is little overhead especially  if there are a lot of commands but it will do the trick. Command for that is :

```
su - <user> -c "<command>"
```

In your case :

```
shipit.remote('su - devuser -c "pwd"');
```

You were on right track with your example.

Best regards,
Nikola

Comment: Thanks @nicola-loncar. Your answer is pretty sound and I'm gonna try it ASAP.

Comment: Is it possible to use it with shipit-deploy tasks? Because it is not customisable